# Statements about complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose that $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ real matrix with $k$ **distinct** real eigenvalues and $l$ **distinct** complex (i.e., non-real) eigenvalues. Consider the following statements:
>
> $(i)$ $k=2,l=0$
>
> $(ii)$ $k=0,l=3$
>
> $(iii)$ $k=1,l=2$
>
> $(iv)$ $k=2,l=1$
>
> How many of the above statements are possible?
>
> $(A)$ None
>
> $(B)$ $1$
>
> $(C)$ $2$
>
> $(D)$ $3$
>
> $(E)$ all of them

I think that only statements $(i)$ and $(iii)$ are possible. Complex numbers come in conjugate pairs so $l \neq 3,1$ So that means either $l=0,2$. Thus, only statements $(i)$ and $(iii)$ are possible so the answer is $(C)$.

Is that the correct train of thought? Thanks!

Comment: Do we assume $A$ has real entries, or any complex entries?

Comment: @coffeemath $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ **real** matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to demonstrate that $(i)$ and $(iii)$ are indeed possible. Giving an example of each case is probably the easiest way to do that. Might I suggest
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $(i)$ and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $(iii)$?

Also, "Complex numbers come in conjugate pairs" is possibly a bit vague. A better way of saying that would be something like "The characteristic equation is a polynomial equation with real coefficients, and complex solutions to such equations come in conjugate pairs."

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

For this its better we consider the characteristic equation of $A$.

$(i)$ Characteristic equation = $(\lambda-a)^2(\lambda-b) \qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}\qquad$ and

$(iii)$ Characteristic equation = $(\lambda-a)(\lambda^2 +b)\qquad a\in\mathbb{R},\;b\in\mathbb{R}^+\qquad$ are possible.

For $(ii)$ and $(iv)$, note that complex eigenvalues, concerning the characteristic equation with real coefficients, always occur in conjugate pairs.

@FutureMathPerson: Your arguments for $l$ are correct but your answer is incomplete since you have not mentioned anything about $k$.